# Magento 2. Observer event on every page loaded after?

Tags: event-observer, magento2.2.2

I'm calling my custom .phtml template from observer. The template is being called successfully and the HTML is displayed correct.

However this .phtml is executed before site's css and javascripts is loaded.

In the screenshot (source code from browser) it shows my custom template is loaded before everything and displayed on the top of the page. This makes jquery inside the template not working.

[image]

Which event should I use so that my custom .phtml is loaded after all site css and javascripts?

I have tried the following events with no luck,

```
controller_action_postdispatch_cms_index_index
store_load_after
controller_action_postdispatch
```

Comment: Add that script in require as  script exist after your `$('.x-button').on` script.

Comment: Thanks, This could be a solution. but doesn't Magento has something that allow us to load the .phtml after all other page content is loaded?

Comment: No,  we can not do that but yes we can load HTML by JS after load all content.